# How to identify first , second etc Monday or other day of week for a given month in excel

Tags: excel

I was looking in internet, but the formulas look so complicated. Any clever suggestions?
/i.e for example I need a formula that identify which date is the first Monday in August 2014, similar to be used- for the second Monday, etc/
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code

```
=A2+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(A2,2),7)
```

Where your A2 cell will contain 01/Month/year like 01/march/2014 but make sure it must have to start with 01.

Comment: You can actually get rid of `MOD` function - this will give the same result =A2+7-WEEKDAY(A2+5) where A2 is 1st of the relevant month. the 5 can be changed depending on the day of week you require

Answer (score 14):

Generically, you can find the **n**-th of an **x** day of a given **M** and **Y** with this formula

`=DATE(Y,M,(n*7)+1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(Y,M,8-x), 2)`

where x is a number representing the day of the week from 1 = Sunday through to 7 = Saturday

So from that **1st** **Monday** in **August** **2014** is found by this formula

`=DATE(2014,8,(1*7)+1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(2014,8,(8-1)), 2)`

If you want the **last** Monday in any given month you can find the first Monday of the next month and subtract 7

See my article [here](http://excelplaza.com/ep_houdini/article_001_variable_holidays/houdini_001_variable_holidays.php) for more

Comment: Thank you. But here I think August is Hardcoded, I want to make the formula flexible, so just to change the reporting month in some other Cell). Please advise how to adjust the formula

Comment: The month and year are completely flexible, 8 represents August here so for the first Monday in October, for example, you just change 8 to 10, e.g. =DATE(2014,**10**,8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(2014,**10**,6)) - if you want you can refer to a cell for month and/or year

Comment: Barry, the link to your article is broken and Google isn't very helpful.  Is there a new location I can find it?  Thanks

Comment: OK, I fixed it - now links to a Word document on dropbox containing the article and a associated excel workbook

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter answer:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A1-1,1,"0111111")
```

where A1 is the cell that contains your date.

The second parameter is the nth day of the week that you want. In this case, 1 = the 1st, 2 = 2nd etc. Depending on the month, you can get up to a 5th occurrence of the same day.

Bonus: you can count the nth day of the week that you want beyond the month!

The third parameter is bitwise. There are seven binary digits, put a "0" on the day that your looking for and then one for the rest. The first digit is Monday up to the seventh digit for Sunday. In this example "0111111" gives you mondays.

Sample 2:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A1-1,3,"1101111")
```

Here, you're looking for the 3rd Wednesday after the date in cell A1.

More on `WORKDAY.INTL` [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d).

Answer (score 0):

> =ROUNDUP(DAY("08/06/2022")/7)

[For clarity, look at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyaQm.jpg)

If the day of the month is in the first seven days of that month, then that day of the week is the first time in that month. If the day of the month is included in the numbers from 8 to 14 (inclusive), then the day of the week of this number was repeated twice