# List of 1st and 3rd Mondays in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I'd like a list of the 1st and 3rd Mondays in each month, for say the next six months after today.

Using a formula-based approach, I can find the 1st or 3rd Monday after today. I got stuck when trying to populate the list after that. Particularly, a challenge is to account for months with 5 Mondays in them. The formulas get very complex very quickly!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That question is duplicated. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169812/how-to-identify-first-second-etc-monday-or-other-day-of-week-for-a-given-month

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Thank you, but that is not a solution to my problem. I need a list of the **next _n_ occurrences**, not just a single result.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have so far:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()

Dim i, mday As Integer
Dim row, col As Integer
Dim d As Date
Dim min As Integer

min = 14    'Minimum set up period

col = 1     'Column to put results in
row = 2     'Row to start from


d = Date + min + 9 - Weekday(Date) 'Find Monday after Minimum set up period

Worksheets("options").Activate

For i = 1 To 26     'Results up to 26 weeks in future
    mday = day(d)
    If (mday - 7 <= 0) Then                                'First week
        Cells(row, col).Value = d
        row = row + 1
    ElseIf (mday - 14 > 0 And mday - 21 <= 0) Then        'Third week
        Cells(row, col).Value = d
        row = row + 1
    End If
    d = d + 7   '+1 week
    Next

Worksheets("New Starter").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On A1 place the first day of one month. On A2 place: `=EOMONTH(A1,0)+1`

On B1 place `=A1+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(A22,2),7).`

On C1 place `=B1+14`

Drag an drop down.

The first column is taking the first day of one month and consecutive month, the column `B`is returning the first monday and colunm `C` is returning the third monday of that month.

If you are looking for the 5th monday:

On D1 place: `=IF(A1+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(A22,2),7)+28<EOMONTH(A1,0)+1,A1+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(A22,2),7)+28,"")`

Comment: Also we should give the formula for A1, how to find the first day of the current month.

Comment: I just place a random date on A1 as it is not indicated on the question, it is just an issue to formulate it.

Comment: @Ted209... in your original question you request to know the 1st and 3rd monday of each month so... what is the issue with the months with more than 3 mondays? Is there any other condition?

Comment: Thanks David. There is one issue with that method though - the results will be out of whack after any month that contains 5 Mondays

Comment: Apologies for the typo - should have been "5 Mondays". The issue is that in a month with 5 Mondays, you'll get the 1st, 3rd, and 5th Monday in the list. The following month you'll get the 2nd and 4th. So, all the results will be out of kilter after that.

Comment: I think a way to mitigate this issue would be to check if the previous two rows had the same month - and if so, add 21 instead of 14.

Comment: @Ted209 this code according to your question, so, if there is additionals conditions: Need of the 5th monday... Edit your post an include it, please